# Extracting multi values with regex ( Only values, Not Fieldname )

Tags: regex, splunk, rex

Can someone help me with this regex?
I would like to extract either 1. or 2.

1.

```
(2624594000) 303 days, 18:32:20.00  <-- Timeticks
.1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.6.3.39.        <-- OID
Hex-STRING: 54 4A 00 C8 73 70   <-- Hex-STRING (need "Hex-STRING" ifself too)
0                                   <--INTEGER
"NJTHAP027"                         <- STRING
```

OR

2.

```
Timeticks: (2624594000) 303 days, 18:32:20.00
OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.6.3.39
Hex-STRING: 54 4A 00 C8 73 70
INTEGER: 0
STRING: "NJTHAP027"
```

- This filedname and value will return different data each time. (The data will be variable.)

I don't need to get the field names and only want to get the values in order from the top (multi value)

```
(?s)[^=]+\s=\s(?<value_v2c>([^=]+)-)
```

https://regex101.com/r/lsKeEM/2
-> I can't extract the last STRING: "NJTHAP027" at all!

Comment: what does the sample data actually look like? The two bits you've got posted are very different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The named group `value_v2c` is already a group, so you can omit the inner capture group.

Currently the `-` char should always be matched in the pattern, but you can either match it or assert the end of the string.

As you are using negated character classes and `[^=]+` and `\s`, you can omit the inline modifier `(?s)` as both already match newlines.

To match the `2.` variation, you can update the pattern to:

```
[^=]+\s=\s(?<value_v2c>[^=]+)(?:-|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9rIBw5/1)

To get the `1.` version, you can match all before the colon as long as it is not Hex-String.

Then in the group optionally match it.

```
[^=]+\s=\s(?:(?!Hex-STRING:)[^:])*:?\s*(?<value_v2c>(?:Hex-STRING: )?[^=]+?)(?: -|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gfWQMO/1)

Comment: Thanks for your support! I was able to learn how to use StackOverFlow from you!

Comment: @Mint You are most welcome, hope you will enjoy this beautiful platform!